# Add and rest one day to date string

Tags: typescript

I have an date that can be date or datetime, for example:
2021-04-13

2021-04-14T00:00:00.000Z

both are strings, so I need to add or subtract one day to each date, but also If a date have the last day of month and I add one day, I need to change the month, or year if is the last month of the month, and the same for the date where I need to subtract to the first day of the month.
I'm working with typescript

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "rest"? Also, are the dates always in either of the two formats you've provided as examples? ie. is it always `yyyy-MM-dd` or UTC DateTime? Or are there other formats like `dd/MM/yyyy` or `MM dd yyyy`?

Comment: @CallumMorrisson for rest I mean subtract, sorry, I already change it.
Yes I'm always receive yyyy-mm-dd and some times it can have time "2021-04-14T00:00:00.000Z"

Comment: So the goal is to add/subtract a day and return the same format as what was input?

Comment: @CallumMorrisson Yes, it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After clarification in the comments, I'm fairly sure this will do what you want:

```
function modifyDate(input: string, dayModification: number): string {
  // regex that will match ####-##-## where # is a number
  const isDateOnlyRegex = /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/;

  // javascript will natively understand both formats when parsing a string to Date
  const date = new Date(input);
  // add the dayModification value as days to the date
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + dayModification);

  // check if it's a dateOnly string
  if (isDateOnlyRegex.test(input)) {
    // using string format to return yyyy-MM-dd format
    return `${date.getFullYear()}-${date.getMonth()+1}-${date.getDate()}`;
  }

  // date.toJSON returns yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ
  // could also use date.toISOString
  return date.toJSON();
}
```

Tests [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#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-k96q+zi7Ywh-l83ux16qd7vv6gbBgGYYBlGB7vkeErMLcdpnheW7cO+w5fhmEH1jmRIwSwcHrpurbXsWdTIZ+XaCj2VpAA) (click `Run` at the top to get  the console output)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by creating a new date based on the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC using [`valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf) and offsetting it by the number of days in milliseconds that you would like to add.

See example below:

```js
function addDays(date, days) {
  return new Date(
    date.valueOf()                 // convert to milliseconds
    + days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000   // add number of days in milliseconds
  )
}

// long date
let date = new Date('2021-04-14T00:00:00.000Z');

console.log(addDays(date, 1));
console.log(addDays(date, -1));

// short date
date = new Date('2021-04-14');

// different month
console.log(addDays(date, 20));
console.log(addDays(date, -20));


// different year
console.log(addDays(date, 320));
console.log(addDays(date, -320));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use moment.js *add* and *subtract* method.

Ex.

```
import moment from 'moment'
const date: string = "2021-04-30";
console.log(moment(date).add(1, "d"));
console.log(moment(date).subtract(10, "d"));
```

[Check the docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/)

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to timestamp

Add 1 day time stamp to it

```
day = 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000;
```